# Tile Palette problem in Unity

Tags: unity, tilemap, isometric

I am working on isometric tilemap in Unity 2019.4.8f1.

In the Tile Palette panel, the selection is always 1 block away. Please see this screenshot:

[image: Tile Palette screenshot]

In the screenshot, apparently I selected an empty tile, but in fact I am select the green tile with flowers. How come? Every selection is one tile away. The same issue happens in the Tilemap selection mode too. I have to select the adjacent tile in order to select the tile I want.

How do I fix it? It's quite annoying.

*UPDATE* I have added the settings of Grid, Tilemap as well as the import settings of the tile sprite sheet below.

[image: Tilemap settings]

[image: Grid settings]

[image: Tile sprite sheet import settings]

[image: Sprite editor settings]

---

*UPDATE 2* Changed the Pivot in Sprite Editor to **Bottom Center**

Recreated the Tile Palette, and it looks like hovering 0.5 unit up.

[image: Pivot bottom center]

Comment: How are the pivots configured on these tile sprites?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Tile Anchor at Tilemap is X: 0.5, Y: 0.5, Z: 0. For the Grid, all anchor and pivot values are 0.5.

Comment: And for the individual tile sprites? Where is their pivot set?

Comment: @DMGregory thanks for asking. Since I'm not 100% sure what you are asking for, I have added the screenshot of the settings in the question. Hope you can locate the problem for me, really thanks.

Comment: See where [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJR7X.png) says "Pivot: Bottom-Left"? Do you observe any change if you set this to middle/center for all your tile sprites, then re-create your tiles/palette?

Comment: I changed to "Bottom Center" and regenerated the tiles, now hovering 0.5 unit up. See the updates above. (The reason I didn't choose Center-Center is that, the tiles have different heights, I would like to align them at the bottom edge)

Comment: To solve the different heights issue, use "Custom" and adjust the y position of the pivot as needed.

Comment: thanks, now works perfectly. Would you mind to write it as an answer, so I can vote it as correct solution?

Comment: Since you have your actual project to be able to.take screenshots of the settings that worked for you, I think you'd be in a batter position to write a clear and detailed answer, if you'd be willing. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DMGregory, the problem is resolved. The root cause of the problem is the Pivot configured in the Sprite Editor is incorrect.

After setting the Pivot to "Center", regenerate the tiles and reset the Tilemap pivot points to X=0.5, Y=0.5, Z=0, the selection in the Tile Palette panel becomes normal again.