# The tile cursor is not on the same tile I selected

Tags: unity, tilemap, tiles

[image: Tilemap]

Here is the image, when I select the tile I want to paint, it paints in the correct box where I want it to be but the white cursor should also be in the same box but it is 2 units to the left? This really  makes it difficult to paint the tiles. I'm a beginner in unity and can't seem to fix this problem :(

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This problem looks [similar to the one this user was having](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/185408/39518). Does that Q&A help you solve your issue?

Comment: Hi there, thank you for pointing it out! unfortunately I tried following it but it still didn't work out. My sprites pivot is already at center and my tilemap pivot points are X= 0.5,Y=0.5,Z= 0.5 should I change the Z to 0?

Comment: nvm, I solved it i have no idea why but my X coordinates in the grid were automatically set to 2? thats werid but thank you for your help! @DMGregory

Comment: Want to share your solution as an Answer below?